# Changing Values in every Sheet and keep the value in every sheet

Tags: vba, excel

So, the information

```
Sheet1 "A1"
Sheet2 "A1"
Sheet3 "A1"
```

Now I want that all these sheets share the same value, doesn't matter which value.
But I have to be able to change this value in every sheet.
For example: The value is 20.

```
Sheet1 A1's value = 20

Sheet2 A1's value = 20

Sheet3 A1's value = 20
```

Now I have sheet 2 open, and I change the 20 to 30.

```
Sheet1 A1's value = now 30

Sheet2 A1's value = now 30

Sheet3 A1's value = now 30
```

Then I notice something else in sheet 3, and I change this value to 50

```
Sheet1 A1's value = now 50

Sheet2 A1's value = now 50

Sheet3 A1's value = now 50
```

As final thing I go back to Sheet 1 and I see that I made a miscalculation, instead of 50 it has to be 40. So I change the value to 40.

```
Sheet1 A1's value = now 40

Sheet2 A1's value = now 40

Sheet3 A1's value = now 40
```

How can I do this? I've tried to put this in every sheet:

```
Private sub Worksheet_Change (Byval target as range)
```

But as soon as I get 3 or more sheets, `"this function is not defined"`

I've searched the internet for like 4 hours now. I tried different things but I just can't get it right.

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: please post your code with `Worksheet_Change`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `sheet` as needed for each sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Cells(1, 1) Then
    sheet2.Cells(1, 1) = Cells(1, 1)
    sheet3.Cells(1, 1) = Cells(1, 1)
    sheet4.Cells(1, 1) = Cells(1, 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy, just force the value changes inside the `Worksheet_Change` event of each of your tracked sheets:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) '<-- in Sheet 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) '<-- in Sheet 2
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) '<-- in Sheet 3
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value
End Sub
```

P.s. The above will change every cell in the three sheets. You need to add a check if you only want the A1 to be updated, which means:

```
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    'change values
End If
```